# Javascript in PDF double values

Tags: javascript, pdf, foxit

I have the following code that is supposed to do a sum in a pdf.

```
var sum = 0.0;
var f1 = this.getField("price");
var temp = parseFloat(f1.value);
sum = temp;

var total = this.getField("total");
if(sum > 0)
{
  total.value = sum;
}
else
{
  total.value = "";
}
```

But if the input is

```
18.31
```

my total is

```
18
```

**EDIT**: I also tried

```
console.println(f1.value);
```

But the value of f1.value is only 18.

**EDIT:** this is running in the javascript interpreter in the [foxit pdf](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/reader_2/whatsnew23.htm) reader.

**EDIT:** I have confirmed there is a bug in the foxit reader javascript interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `parseFloat()` converts `f1.value` (if it is a number) into a string, rounding it along the way, depending on what the `toString()` method of the object returns.

Try without it.

http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html#tcParseFl

Comment: Did you get what he is asking ? I do not understand the question.

Comment: I guess I should ask a new question.
Why is a fields value truncated?

Comment: Do you have a `maxlength` attribute set?